# Power spectral density of a optical modulated signal intensity

Tags: power-spectral-density

If $E(t)$ is a carrier modulated by a complex baseband signal, what is the PSD of $|E(t)|^2$?

Comment: Hi, welcome to DSP.SE! Please note that asking a question with a brief statement (unless succinct) is discouraged all across the StackExchange network.. Please show us the work that you have done thus far to solve your problem.